# speech synthesis in perl

Tags: perl, speech, speech-synthesis

Is it possible to make computer (windows or linux, mac) speak in perl ?  I know it is possible with VB script. But how about perl ?

In VB we just write

```
CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice").Speak"I can speak "
```

How do we do this in perl ?

Comment: Search CPAN (http://search.cpan.org/) for TTS (Text-to-speech)

Comment: KDE Jovie, Gnome Speech, Festival, flite, espeak, epos

Comment: Whenever you want to know if Perl can do something, start by searching CPAN at https://metacpan.org . You'll have an answer in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Speech::Synthesis](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Speech%3a%3aSynthesis) module can interface to Microsoft's SAPI 5 API, which it looks like you're using in VB.  There's also [Win32::SAPI5](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aSAPI5), which is Windows-specific but may offer more control, or you can just use [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE):

```
use Win32::OLE;

Win32::OLE->CreateObject('SAPI.SpVoice')->Speak('I can speak');
```

Of course, if you're going to speak multiple times, you'd probably want to create the object only once, store it in a variable, and call `Speak` multiple times on it.

Answer (score 2):

A quick [CPAN](http://www.cpan.org/) search shows that [PerlSpeak](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PerlSpeak), [Speech::Synthesis](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Speech%3a%3aSynthesis), and [Speech::eSpeak](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Speech%3a%3aeSpeak) all are capable of speech synthesis.